# React - useState - why setTimeout function does not have latest state value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Recently I was working on React Hooks and got stuck with one problem/doubt?

Below is a basic implementation to reproduce the issue, Here I'm just toggling `flag` (a state) variable on click of the button.

```
  const [flag, toggleFlag] = useState(false);
  const data = useRef(null);
  data.current = flag;

  const _onClick = () => {
    toggleFlag(!flag);
    // toggleFlag(!data.current); // working

    setTimeout(() => {
      toggleFlag(!flag); // does not have latest value, why ?
      // toggleFlag(!data.current); // working
    }, 2000);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={_onClick}>{flag ? "true" : "false"}</button>
    </div>
  );
```

I figured out some other way to overcome this problem like using useRef or useReducer, but is this correct or is there any other way to solve this with useState only?

Also, **it would be really helpful if anyone explains why we get old value of state inside the setTimeout**.

Sandbox URL - https://codesandbox.io/s/xp540ynomo

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This boils down to how closures work in JavaScript. The function given to `setTimeout` will get the `flag` variable from the initial render, since `flag` is not mutated.

You could instead give a function as argument to `toggleFlag`. This function will get the correct `flag` value as argument, and what is returned from this function is what will replace the state.

**Example**

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [flag, toggleFlag] = useState(false);

  const _onClick = () => {
    toggleFlag(!flag);

    setTimeout(() => {
      toggleFlag(flag => !flag)
    }, 2000);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={_onClick}>{flag ? "true" : "false"}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Doesn't `_onClick` get a new closure and a new `flag` value on every render?

Comment: @UjinT34 Yes, but when `_onClick` is first invoked the timeout is created, and then when the timeout function is invoked some time later, `flag` will be looked up in the context of the initial render, so it will get the "old" value.

Comment: When does the closure fot `setTimeout` get created? I thought that it is created every time `_onClick` is called and gets the `flag` captured by `_onClick` and not the original `flag` variable.

Comment: @UjinT34 I think it will make sense if you think of `App` as a function, and every re-render will cause a new call to the `App` function. The first call to `App` does not "see" the variables in the second call to `App`.

Comment: May be I got the "initial render" wrong. For me it sounds like `setTimeout` has `flag = false` forever as it was on the first `App` call. Please, check my answer.

Comment: @UjinT34 Yes, you are right in that the function given to `setTimeout` in the initial render will always see `flag = false`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to have the up-to-date value of a state variable in `setTimeout` then you should use `refs`

```js
const App = () => {
  const messageRef = useRef('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    // THIS IS THE MAGIC PART
    messageRef.current = message;
  }, [message]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setMessage(e.target.value);
  };

  const sendMessage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(() => {
      // The most recent value of _message_ variable
      alert(messageRef.current);
    }, 2000);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input onChange={handleChange} value={message} />
      <button onClick={sendMessage}>
        Send message
      </button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Read more: https://felixgerschau.com/react-hooks-settimeout/

Answer (score 3):

The function given to `setTimeout` will get the `flag` variable from the `_onClick` function. The `_onClick` function gets created every render and "stores" the value which the `flag` variable gets on this render.

```
function App() {
  const [flag, toggleFlag] = useState(false);
  console.log("App thinks that flag is", flag);

  const _onClick = () => {
    console.log("_onClick thinks that flag is", flag);
    toggleFlag(!flag);

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("setTimeout thinks that flag is", flag);
    }, 100);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={_onClick}>{flag ? "true" : "false"}</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Console:

```
App thinks that flag is false

_onClick thinks that flag is false
App thinks that flag is true
setTimeout thinks that flag is false

_onClick thinks that flag is true
App thinks that flag is false
setTimeout thinks that flag is true
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply, when you call setTimeout, the function goes with the values you send and put in a queue with the values at the moment you call, and after a certain period of time, they are executed using the values at the moment you call.
Instead you can follow the change of the variable with useEffect and get the most current value if you setTimeout in useEffect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Mert shouldn't it will create closure around the variables being used in callback for setTimout ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this package created to address this specific "old state values in inner functions" problem: https://github.com/Aminadav/react-useStateRef