# Hiding an element after a while in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, settimeout, show-hide

I have a header component as a function component. I want show a popup when logo text is clicked. After for a time it should close automatically. I use hooks for state of popup. But set state function doesn't work in setTimeout function. How can fix this?

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import style from './header.module.css'

const Header = () => {
  const [popupOpen, setPopupOpen] = React.useState(false)

  return (
    <header className={style.header}>
      <nav className={style.nav}>
        <div
          className={style.popupContainer}
          onClick={() => {
            setPopupOpen(!popupOpen)
            console.log(popupOpen)
            setTimeout(() => {
              console.log(popupOpen)
              setPopupOpen(!popupOpen)
              console.log(popupOpen)
            }, 1000)
          }}
        >
          <span className={style.logo}>Logo</span>

          <span
            className={`${style.popupText} ${
              popupOpen ? style.show : style.hide
            }`}
          >
            Popup Text
          </span>
        </div>

        <ul className={style.ul}>
          <li>
            <Link href='/'>
              <a>.home</a>
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link href='/contact'>
              <a>.contact</a>
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Console log:

[image: console log]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me suggests, this is the same question as:

[React - useState - why setTimeout function does not have latest state value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55198517/react-usestate-why-settimeout-function-does-not-have-latest-state-value)

```
const _onClick = () => {
     setPopupOpen(!popupOpen);

     setTimeout(() => {
         setPopupOpen(popupOpen => !popupOpen)
     }, 2000);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Its happening because `setPopupOpen` is asynchronous. So by the time `setPopupOpen(!popupOpen)` is called it has same value as `onClick` first `setPopupOpen(!popupOpen)` so eventually when it called both `setPopup doing same state update` i.e both updating as `false`. Better way is to use`setPopupOpen` callback function to update the value. I added this code.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import style from "./style.module.css";

const Header = () => {
  const [popupOpen, setPopupOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => {
    setPopupOpen((prev) => !prev);
  };
  const onClick = () => {
    setPopupOpen(!popupOpen);
    setTimeout(() => {
      toggle();
    }, 1000);
  };

  return (
    <header className={style.header}>
      <nav className={style.nav}>
        <div className={style.popupContainer} onClick={onClick}>
          <span className={style.logo}>Logo</span>

          {popupOpen && (
            <span
              className={`${style.popupText} ${
                popupOpen ? style.show : style.hide
              }`}
            >
              Popup Text
            </span>
          )}
        </div>

        <ul className={style.ul}>
          <li>
            <Link href="/">
              <a>.home</a>
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link href="/contact">
              <a>.contact</a>
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};

export default function IndexPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-haibt-iqecz?file=/pages/index.js:0-1212