# MUI switch doesn't work first time react state

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a very simple problem and I'm stuck:

- I have a simple MUI react switch with state tracker
- It doesn't work first time, but it works all subsequent times...
  EDIT: specifically the state is not updated the first time, the lgos show false, false, true, false, true instead of false, true, false, true etc

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
```

```
  const handleChange = () => {
    setChecked(!checked);
    if(image.file != null){
      displayImage(image.file);
    }
  };
```

```
<FormGroup>
<FormControlLabel control={<Switch checked={checked} onChange={handleChange} color="secondary"/>} label="Center Image" />
</FormGroup>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what doesn't work the first time? Is the switch not being checked on the first click? The MUI switch worked fine as I tested the code (without the image part).
If the problem is with showing the image, this example does not provide information on where the problem could be other than `image.file` being null or `displayImage` not doing what you intend it to do.

Comment: It doesnt update state, logs showing: false, false, true, false, true etc... instead of false, ture, false, true.. The rest works perfectly (image display etc) maybe the problem is somewhere else then..

Comment: The answer is here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66039282/2822041

Answer (score 0):

This will make it work:

```
  const handleChange = () => {
    setChecked(!checked);
  };
```

and

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(image.file != null){
      displayImage(image.file);
    }
  }, [checked]);
```