# How do I remove the delay between pushing the button and the first sound?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, timer, web-audio-api, metronome

I made a metronome inspired by the famous Chris Wilson's article using React, Hooks, and the Web Audio API.

The metronome works but there's a delay between the moment I hit 'play' and the sound itself.

This is clearly noticeable if the BPM is very low (e.g. 40 BPM).

At first, I thought I needed to isolate the logic from the UI rendering using a Worker but now I start to think it's something else.

I think in the `timer` function I need an `else` calling `sound` with a 0 value.
But I haven't found a solution yet.

Does anybody have an idea what's wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks!

```
import { useState } from 'react';

let ac;
let lastNote = 0;
let nextNote = 0;
let engine;

function App() {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [bpm] = useState(40);

  const oneBeatInSeconds = 60000 / bpm / 1000;
  ac = new AudioContext();

  const sound = (ac: AudioContext, time: number, dur: number) => {
    // creates the sound, connects it and decides when it starts and stops
    const osc = ac.createOscillator();
    osc.connect(ac.destination);
    osc.start(time);
    osc.stop(time + dur);
  };

  const timer = () => {
    // Calculates how long it was in ms from loading the browser to clicking the play button
    const diff = ac.currentTime - lastNote;

    // Schedules the next note if the diff is larger then the setInterval
    if (diff >= oneBeatInSeconds) {
      nextNote = lastNote + oneBeatInSeconds;
      lastNote = nextNote;
      sound(ac, lastNote, 0.025);
    }
    ac.resume();
  };

  if (isPlaying) {
    // If the metronome is playing resumes the audio context
    ac.resume();
    clearInterval(engine);
    engine = setInterval(timer, oneBeatInSeconds);
  } else {
    // If the metronome is stopped, resets all the values
    ac.suspend();
    clearInterval(engine);
    lastNote = 0;
    nextNote = 0;
  }

  const toggleButton = () =>
    isPlaying === true ? setIsPlaying(false) : setIsPlaying(true);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="Bpm">
        <label className="Bpm_label" htmlFor="Bpm_input">
          {bpm} BPM
        </label>
        <input type="range" min="40" max="200" step="1" value={bpm} />
      </div>
      <button type="button" className="PlayButton" onClick={toggleButton}>
        {!isPlaying ? 'play' : 'stop'}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Your code to actually play the sound is buried inside useEffect which is likely triggered after a call to useState (via the toggleButton) function. That's a lot of "wait for react to get around to it" delay.  Can you structure your code such that the audio objects are stored globally or in a context object such that clicking the button invokes the Audio apis directly?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if this is the root cause of your sound playing delay.  It's just a hypothesis.

Comment: I'm not sure. I tried also a "minimal" version with no useEffect, and no UI-rendering, and the problem is still there.

Comment: Maybe you could post the "minimal" version?  aka [mcve] which is well liked on SO.

Comment: I edited to the minimal version

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant but FWIW:
`setInterval(foo, delay)` will run the function `foo` only after `delay` milliseconds have passed. This doesn't mean that `foo` function will be run immediately after each `delay` milliseconds interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to play the first beep at once you can directly schedule it in near future without using `setInterval`. Additionally, it is better to run the function, that schedules the next beep, by `setTimeout` each time instead of using `setIntervall`. This makes sure that the beat always is aligned to the time frame that is used by the `AudioContext`. Here is a simplified example based on your code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const duration = 0.1;
const bpm = 40;
const shortDelta = 0.01;
const oneBeatInSeconds = 60000 / bpm / 1000;

let ac;
let nextBeep = 0;

function scheduleNextBeep() {
    let thisBeep = nextBeep;

    if (thisBeep > 0) {
        // schedule the next beep short before it shall be played
        nextBeep += oneBeatInSeconds;
        setTimeout(scheduleNextBeep, (nextBeep - ac.currentTime) * 1000 - shortDelta);

        // schedule this beep
        const osc = ac.createOscillator();
        osc.connect(ac.destination);
        osc.start(thisBeep);
        osc.stop(thisBeep + duration);
    }
}

function App() {
    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        ac = new AudioContext();
    }, []);

    function toggleButton() {
        if (isPlaying) {
            setIsPlaying(false);
            nextBeep = 0;
        } else {
            setIsPlaying(true);
            // schedule the first beep
            nextBeep = ac.currentTime + shortDelta;
            scheduleNextBeep();
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="Bpm">{bpm} BPM</div>
            <button type="button" onClick={toggleButton}>
                {isPlaying ? 'stop' : 'play'}
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**Update 07/15/2022**

As discussed in the comments you can improve the quality of the "beep" sound by using a nice sample wav instead of the `OscillatorNode`. If you definitely need the oscillator for some reason you can apply an envelope to the beep like this:

```
function scheduleNextBeep() {
    let thisBeep = nextBeep;

    if (thisBeep > 0) {
        // schedule the next beep short before it shall be played
        nextBeep += oneBeatInSeconds;
        setTimeout(scheduleNextBeep, (nextBeep - ac.currentTime) * 1000 - shortDelta);

        // prepare this beep
        const oscNode = ac.createOscillator();
        const gainNode = ac.createGain();
        oscNode.connect(gainNode);
        gainNode.connect(ac.destination);

        // set envelope of beep
        gainNode.gain.value = 1.0;
        gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(1.0, thisBeep + duration * 0.7);
        gainNode.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.00001, thisBeep + duration);

        // schedule this beep
        oscNode.start(thisBeep);
        oscNode.stop(thisBeep + duration);
    }
}
```

Comment: I made an edit in code to bring it closer to the author's original code. Added a `useEffect` to initialize `ac`, this `useEffect` will run after component has been rendered. Just in case if this application is server-side-rendered, then initializing `audioContext` on server would become a problem, hence this `useEffect` will help.

Comment: @Aman Godara: Thank you for pointing this out. There may be even more possible improvements regarding react. Main focus of my answer is the timing part.

Comment: @Markus Thanks a lot! This is pretty close to what I'm trying to achieve. There is still a 'click' every time the oscillator stops. You can notice it with a bigger BPM like 120... Is this because of `setTimeout`?

Comment: @Marco Mazzai The click that you perceive is when the oscillator's sine curve is stopped in the middle of a wave. Natural sounds don't stop immediately. You can add a `GainNode` and configure a decay ramp or you can use an `AudioBufferSourceNode` with a natural sample sound of your choice instead of using the `OscillatorNode`. Here is a good explanation of what is happening: https://alemangui.github.io/ramp-to-value

Comment: @Markus Would this solution work using `useState` as well? It seems like `thisBeep` won't get update on re-render with `useState`.

Comment: @Marco Mazzai Not shure if I get your point. The solution uses `useState`, doesn't it?

Comment: @Markus Yes, I explained it badly. ;) The solution works, and `thisBeep` gets updated. I was wondering if it is possible to use a `useState` for `thisBeep` and `nextBeep` as well instead of normal constants. Will the app have too many re-renders? I wonder if it's normal practice to have both `useState` constants and "normal" constants.

Comment: @Marco Mazzai I would only use the `useState` hook if I want the UI to be updated. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55198556/18667225) answer your question? If you need more help, you should create a new question regarding this very topic. I'm shure you can even strip out the web audio part to have a minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

This a minor bug,
one possible solution could be thinking about `setInterval` a bit.
`setInterval` function runned with a delay ..

You can try to call your `timer` function outside the `setInterval` .

And for more information you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685396/execute-the-).

setinterval-function-without-delay-the-first-time

In short answer what I mean is that if you try to use `setInterval` with 200 ms interval , the first time that your function called is not exactly 200 ms :)

Nice solution:

```
(function foo() {
  ...
  setTimeout(foo, delay);
})();
```